# Yehi Ratzons on Monday and Thursday only?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, fast-days, shacharis-morning-prayer

Are there any recent Halachic sources that discuss whether or not the Yehi Ratzons following the Torah reading would be recited a fast day that falls out on S/T/W/F?

I realize that at [Why are the Yehi Ratzon prayers connected to Tachanun?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64385/why-are-the-yehi-ratzon-prayers-connected-to-tachanun) it is indicated that there is something special about Mondays and Thursdays, however a similar argument could be made for Fast Days, when we say Selichos, or we could just not rule like the view brought there.

Comment: Until this question is opened, refer to http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2008-04-25Tefila_Newsletter.pdf. It seems only Siddur Rav Amram Gaon mentions saying this on Mon. / Thurs. Machzor Vitri has it for Shabbat mincha, and Avudraham has it for Shabbat Mevarchim Hachodesh. So, you can see that various minhagim developed.

Comment: FYI: IIRC In Breuers (The High School & Yeshiva) - circa 1987 - they would say the Yehi Ratzons every day at Mincha after Tachanun.

Comment: @DannySchoemann interesting.  I wonder where that minhag comes from...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות - Apparently during the 6-day war, IIRC, when the main shul also did so. The main shul eventually stopped this addition but the Yeshiva kept it for some reason.

Comment: If you can get hold of a Sefardi siddur such as De Sola Pool's siddur, you'll discover that the *Yehi Ratzon* was designated to be said on the Shabbat before Rosh Hodesh. It seems that this was the original minhag from I believe Rav Amram Gaon's siddur. Moving it to Mon. / Thurs. I think was a much later minhag. I'll see if I can dig up the article from *beurei hatefilah* web site. The point is, for now, that you may want to edit your question to indicate that what you mention is Ashkenazic minhag.

Comment: Wait a sec! In the answer that I gave in the linked question, I pointed you to the *beureihatefilah* article. Look specifically at page 2 of that article. He cites an explanation as to why Mon. & Thurs. specifically were chosen as the Torah reading days. He says that because these days are *et ratzon*, (he explains how we know this), therefore, *Yehi Ratzon* was reserved for Mon. / Thurs. Please re-read this. If it still doesn't answer your question, you may want to ask, separately, if fast days would be considered *Et Ratzon*.

Comment: @DanF I saw it, but I'm asking if that same "Es Ratzon" or similar logic would apply to any Torah reading day where we do not omit Tachanun (i.e. fast days that fall out on STuWF).  That is stated clearly in my question.

Answer (score 3):

I have found in the [Mateh Efrayim 602:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Mateh_Efrayim.602.19) with regards to the Fast of Gedaliah that one should only say *Yehi ratzon* if the fast falls either on Monday or Thursday:

> אם חל בשני וחמישי, אומר הש"ץ בגלילת הספר תורה "יהי רצון מלפני אבינו" כו' והזכרת נשמות, כמו בכל השנה. ואם חל בראשון או ברביעי, אין אומרים "יהי רצון" ולא הזכרת נשמות, רק אם יש יאהר צייט מזכיר נשמתו.‏
>
> If it falls on Monday or Thursday, the prayer leader says at the rolling up of the Torah scroll *Yehi ratzon milifnei avinu etc.* and commemorates the deceased like in the whole year. And if it falls on Sunday or Wednesday, we don't say *Yehi ratzon* and we do not commemorate the deceased, only if there is someone with an anniversary we commemorate the deceased.

Answer (score 2):

See page 2 of this [beureihatefila.org](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2008-01-18_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf) article. It's the same one as in my answer in your linked question.

I did locate a source that posits that a fast day may be considered עת רצון, which would possibly support the idea of saying these *yehi ratzon*. However, I'm inferring that the main reason is attached to the maximum 3-day interval allowed for reading the Torah.

In particular, the Kolbo's explanation states that enemies are more likely to attack if one does not read the Torah within a maximum of 3 days. And, we do see that one of the *Yehi Ratzon* requests is to save us from our enemies.